# Prove $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt[n]{\tan x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \sec (\frac{\pi}{2n})$ without complex techniques

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Prove
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt[n]{\tan x} \,dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \sec \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)$$

for all natural numbers $n \ge 2$.

There are several answers ([A1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4385116/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-sqrtn-tan-theta-d-th?rq=1) [A2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913572#1913572)) to this integral but they all involve the gamma function or the beta function or contour integration  etc. Can one solve this using only 'real' 'elementary' techniques? For $n = 2$ and $n = 3$ it can be solved using only elementary substitutions and partial fractions.

Comment: You may try setting $t^n  = \tan x$ and do something like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4459448

Comment: @Gary Could you explain more about how that would work? I understand I can factorize $x^{2n}+1$ but I'm having trouble making it into partial fractions (how to calculate each numerators).

Comment: The way I could compute it uses the Beta Integral.

Comment: The Beta Integral is usually handled with real methods. I would consider it elementary.

Comment: @robjohn Later in the solution, we would need to use the reflection formula of gamma function. Is there a real proof for that? Please clarify.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari: I posted my answer. I have removed the Beta function and Reflection Formula and folded them into the identity which can be used to prove the Reflection Formula. The [cited answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077) is involved, but totally real.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sqrt[n]{\tan(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{1/n}\,\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{v^{\frac{1-n}{2n}}}{1+v}\,\mathrm{d}v\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac\pi2\csc\left(\pi\frac{n+1}{2n}\right)\tag{1c}\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi2\sec\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: set $x=\tan^{-1}(u)$
$\text{(1b)}$: set $u=v^{1/2}$
$\text{(1c)}$: apply $(2)$ below
$\text{(1d)}$: $\csc(\pi/2+x)=\sec(x)$

Here is the argument from $(3)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216) with more explanation:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{x^{-\alpha}+x^{\alpha-1}}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1\left(x^{k-\alpha}+x^{k+\alpha-1}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{2b}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac1{k-\alpha+1}+\frac1{k+\alpha}\right)\tag{2c}\\
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+\alpha}\tag{2d}\\[6pt]
&=\pi\csc(\pi\alpha)\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: break the integral into two parts: $[0,1]$ and $(1,\infty)$
$\phantom{\text{(2a):}}$ substitute $x\mapsto1/x$ in the second part
$\text{(2b)}$: apply the series for $\frac1{1+x}$
$\text{(2c)}$: evaluate the integrals
$\text{(2d)}$: write as a principal value sum
$\text{(2e)}$: apply $(8)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077)

Comment: I think it's bad form to write $x\mapsto\tan^{-1}(x)$. Better $x\mapsto\tan^{-1}(u)$. Also, you have two equations 1d, and no 1c.

Comment: Since the scope of each of these variables is its individual integral, as long as the substitution is done uniformly, there is no problem. However, I have added new variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Here is to integrate with partial fractions. Utilize the factorization
$ 1+y^{2n} = \prod^n_{k=1} (y^2-2y\cos a_k +1 )$, with $a_k=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt[n]{\tan x} \,dx \\
=&\ \frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt[n]{\tan x}+\sqrt[n]{\cot x} \ {dx }
\overset{y^n=\tan x} = \frac 12\int_0^\infty\frac{n(y^n+y^{n-2})}{1+y^{2n}}dy\\
= &\ \frac12 \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}\sin 2a_k}{y^2-2y\cos a_k +1 }dy
=- \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k}a_k\cos a_k\\
=&-\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k}\sin a_k t\bigg)_{t=1}= - \frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\sin \pi t}{2\cos\frac{\pi t}{2n}}\bigg)_{t=1}
= \frac\pi2 \sec\frac\pi{2n}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt[n]{\tan x} d x&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{\frac{1}{n}} x \cos ^{-\frac{1}{n}} x d x\\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} x \cos^ {2\left(-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1 }x d x\\
&=\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \pi \csc \left[\pi\left(\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \sec \frac{\pi}{2 n}
\end{aligned}
where the second last line using the property of Beta function:

$$B(x, 1-x)=\pi \csc (\pi x) \quad x \notin \mathbb{Z}.$$